# Sql lite "The given key was not present in the dictionary"

Tags: javascript, sqlite, cordova, windows-phone-8.1

I have cordova windows app using a sql lite plugin. Now see two queries doing the same:

```
1) "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Settings (setting TEXT PRIMARY KEY, value TEXT NOT NULL)";
2) "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Settings (setting TEXT, value TEXT NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY(setting))";
```

Unfortunately the second one will fail when

```
"PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON";
```

Unfortunately I have tables having PRIMARY KEY of multiple columns, so need the second syntax.

```
example: PRIMARY KEY(setting, value)
```

Any idea why and how to fix?

Code:

```
let db = window.openDatabase("MFS", "", "MFS database", 52428800);
db.transaction((tx) => {
    let query1 = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Settings (setting TEXT PRIMARY KEY, value TEXT NOT NULL)",
        query2 = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Settings (setting TEXT, value TEXT NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY(setting))";
    tx.executeSql(query1/*query2*/, [], (tx, result, query) => {
    }, (tx, err, query) => {
        alert(err.message);
    }
});
```

Comment: This is not an SQL error message. Show your code.

Comment: @CL.just added code. I think it's SQL error message.

Answer (score 0):

I define a primary key with `CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Settings (setting INTEGER PRIMARY KEY ...` and it worked like a charm:

```
db.transaction(createLocalTableSettings, errorLocalTable, successCreateLocalTableSettings);

function createLocalTableSettings(tx) {
    tx.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Settings (setting INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, value TEXT NOT NULL)');
}
function successCreateLocalTableSettings() {
        console.log('Settings Table successful created');
}
function errorLocalTable(err) {
        console.log("Error creating Settings Table! Processing SQL: " + err.sql + " Parameter: " + JSON.stringify(err.params));
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: this works for me too, but it's same as my working query 1. My query 2 having Primary key definition at the end should work, because I have tables having multiple keys. Also be aware of the "PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON";.